# touch screen failed on my android tablet--my email logged in

Tags: tablet

Touch screen failed on my android tablet. I requested for replacement. The problem is that all my accounts are signed in.I can't give my device back as all accounts are signed in.lets say they repaired the device then they can have access to my gmail account. How can I log off from that tablet since touch is not working. Is there any way that I can do to prevent others from looking into my gmail account and accessing it.can I log off it from my laptop?? please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change the password on your Google account from the web interface. Next time your device tries to connect, it'll be signed out.

You could also boot into the recovery (the way to do this depends on what tablet you have), and factory-reset the tablet from there. The recovery menu is operated by the hard buttons, not the touch screen, so you should still be able to do this.

Comment: yes, I changed the password and to boot into recovery menu, I need to press power button and volume down button right? but it is asking me to select like reboot, power off etc... so to do this touch interface is needed.I couldn't.

Comment: Usually you select the menu items with the volume keys and then activate the selected one with the power button.

Comment: Its not working in this tablet. When I press power button and volume down button, this time it shut down. When I switch on again, its not coming up. I am using digiflip pro ET701 tablet.

Comment: You should add that information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

i have another option for you if possible than connect usb mouse to tablet (you need to purchase converter from the market than connect on the tablet) i have done it and use mouse and another option as touch in tablet. i hope it will useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also lock the tablet from [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager). This way the next time the tablet connects to the internet and Google services, it will be locked with your password. Note that if it doesn't connect via mobile data or WiFi, the lock command won't get through to the tablet, and it will remain open.

Comment: how to lock? any command  please. previously I tried to change permissions by revoke access. After that I couldn't see the device in online.

Answer (score -2):

Dont worry. You can use a mouse to operate the tablet. First, buy an OTG cable for your tablet and then connect the mouse to be able to navigate through the tablet as if you used the touchscreen.